# For centos 7 minimal ldap works but ldaps does not

Tags: openldap, centos7

I have an OpenLDAP server version `openldap-2.4.40` that works fine on CentOS 7 minimal. I tested by issuing:

```
ldapwhoami -H ldap://provider.med.cornell.edu -x \
  -D "cn=Manager,dc=provider,dc=med,dc=cornell,dc=edu" -W
```

But if I use `ldaps://.....` it fails with:

```
ldap_sasl_bind(SIMPLE): Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
```

I have tried configuring this file `/etc/sysconfig/slapd` to no avail.

```
SLAPD_URLS="ldapi:/// ldap:///"
```

This is commented out

```
# SLAPD_URLS="ldapi:/// ldaps:///"

# Any custom options # SLAPD_OPTIONS="-g ldap"
```

If I uncomment

```
#SLAPD_URLS="ldapi:/// ldaps:///"
```

and restart `slapd`, then `ldap:///` will not work either.

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried ldap:/// ldaps:///?

Per this page http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/runningslapd.html, ldapi is ldap over ipc.

Comment: I changed /etc/sysconfig/slapd tp SLAPD_URLS="ldap:/// ldaps:/// ldapi:///", it does not break down ldap search but ldaps still does not work. I have read some where that TLSCACertificateFile should be added, but not sure how.

Comment: That's probably true, we didn't cover the certs, just the ports listening properly.  You'll want to create certs and put them in the appropriate places, and change the config files to match.  Easiest would be to read the documentation, search for, say, openldap certs.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my domain name to provide.example.com and made sure I do the certification right and ldaps worked just fine on the server and added a new user and retrieved through ldapsearch.

Then I setup the client and ran:
ldapwhoami -H ldaps://provider.example.com -x -D "cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com" -W
and did get:
dn:cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com

and will get the newuser01 if I run ldapsearch on the client.

But when I try to run:
getent -s sss passwd newuser01

I get nothing.

The content of my /etc/sssd/sssd.conf is:
[domain/default]

autofs_provider = ldap
cache_credentials = False
ldap_search_base = dc=example,dc=com
krb5_server = #
id_provider = ldap
auth_provider = ldap
chpass_provider = ldap
ldap_uri = ldaps://provider.example.com
ldap_id_use_start_tls = False
ldap_tls_cacertdir = /etc/openldap/cacerts
[sssd]
services = nss, pam, autofs
config_file_version = 2

domains = default
[nss]
homedir_substring = /home

[pam]

[sudo]

[autofs]

[ssh]

[pac]

[ifp]

Of course I authconfig these too
authconfig \
--disablesmartcard \
--disablefingerprint \
--enablesssd \
--enablesssdauth \
--enablelocauthorize \
--disablemd5 \
--passalgo=sha512 \
--enablepamaccess \
--enableldap \
--enableldapauth \
--disableldaptls \
--ldapserver=ldaps://provider.example.com:636 \
--ldapbasedn=dc=example,dc=com \
--enablemkhomedir \
--disablecachecreds \
--disablekrb5 \
--disablekrb5kdcdns \
--disablekrb5realmdns \
--krb5kdc=" #" \
--updateall

I guess this is an answer with a question, not quite sure how to set up a new question or should I be just starting a new question?